# How do I 'cut into' tkinter.tk.mainloop()?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a program, and as you can probably already guess, I'm using `tkinter`. I have seen from other questions on this site that `tk.mainloop()` contains `root.update_idletasks()` and `root.update()`. I also understand that it blocks, and that I can't really run anything in `main()` after it. Maybe threading is the solution, but I'd rather not have to wrap my head around that just yet. My first thought was that I should just abandon `tk.mainloop()` in favor of including these two methods in my own `mainloop()`.

However, I ran into a small problem. I had some tasks that I could toggle on and off with a button. While these tasks were running, if I closed the window, it would crash. If without, it would close gracefully. Why it crashes isn't all that important (mostly because I don't care if it crashes when it's closing, because the user is done with it), but it did tell me that there's more to `mainloop()` than just:

```
def mainloop(self):
    while true
        self.update()
        self.update_idletasks()
```

From what I've seen, I've surmised that parts of tkinter are integrated into the interpreter (or other some such nonsense that means I can't just go in and read it). Thus, here is my question:

What exactly does `tkinter.tk.mainloop()` do? Is the `n` argument a number of times it can run? If so, would there be anything wrong with just running it one iteration inside a method I define, that itself is a loop?

If `n` isn't iterations, what is it? Is there any built-in way I can add tasks to be carried out each loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of Tkinter's actual functionality is implemented in Python; the Python side is just an interface to the embedded Tcl language interpreter, which is where Tk actually lives.  As such, it seems unlikely that you could replace `mainloop()` with anything written in Python.

Fortunately, there's no reason to - Tkinter provides the `after()` and `after_idle()` methods, which allow you to schedule tasks to be performed on a future iteration of the event loop.

Comment: Ah! That makes sense. I was under the impression that `after()` was made for threading. So, from your comment, I can assume that calling `after()` will queue the selected task to be done to be done when `update()` is called? Since this is using callbacks, should I be wrapping the call in a lambda?

Comment: ``after()`` specifies a task that is executed on the first iteration of the event loop after the specified time has elapsed.  ``after_idle()`` executes on the first iteration of the event loop that does not otherwise have any action to take.  Wrapping the call in a lambda should not be necessary, you can supply any needed parameters to your callback as additional parameters to the after/after_idle call.

Comment: Your description of `after_idle` is incorrect. It is just like `after` except that it only processes "idle" events, a subset of all events. Roughly speaking, "idle" events are events such as internal requests to redraw the screen, and of course, events scheduled with `after_idle`